# Sed Pattern Match Which Uses Offset of Line Number in the Replace String?

Tags: bash, sed, pattern-matching, line-numbers, inline-editing

I have a file of a column field type standard (where characters `1` through `6` correspond to `field 1`, `7` through `11` to `field 2`, and so on).

Key attributes are:

- Each line is `80` characters long.
- Text in `field 2` through `field N` are always
  `right` justified within the field.

I have a file like:

```
REMARK   1 
HETATM    1
HETATM    5
HETATM    6
HETATM    7
HETATM    9
HETATM   12
HETATM   15
HETATM   19
HETATM   23
HETATM   27
HETATM   30
HETATM   34
HETATM   38
END
```

For `HETATM` records... lines where the first six atoms equal that string... I want to replace the numbers in second field (characters `7` through `11`) with the entry number, starting with `1`.

i.e. I want the output to appear as:

```
REMARK   1 
HETATM    1
HETATM    2
HETATM    3
HETATM    4
HETATM    5
HETATM    6
HETATM    7
HETATM    8
HETATM    9
HETATM   10
HETATM   11
HETATM   12
HETATM   13
END
```

Currently my most concise solution (using a temporary file for testing, to avoid screwing up my original) is:

```
#!/bin/bash
f=file.pdb
fTmp=${f}.tmp
cp $f $fTmp
for ((l=1; l<$( wc -l $fTmp | awk '{print $1}' ); l++)); do
   sed -i "$((l + 1))"'s#\(HETATM\)[ 0-9]\{5\}#\1'"$( printf '%5s' $l )"'#g' $fTmp
done
cat $fTmp
rm $fTmp
```

Removing the temporary file baggage this becomes:

```
f=file.pdb
for ((l=1; l<$( wc -l $f | awk '{print $1}' ); l++)); do
   sed -i "$((l + 1))"'s#\(HETATM\)[ 0-9]\{5\}#\1'"$( printf '%5s' $l )"'#g' $f
done
```

Seems like there should be some way to use a line number in `sed` to create a briefer solution -- perhaps a single `sed -i` command.  Assuming that's possible the only complexity is that a bit of arithmetic would be necessary -- the first match which should be set to `1` always occurs on the second line.

I'm hoping there's a `sed` solution.  I'm hesitant to use `awk`, as given that space padding is important and inline editing is desired, it seems like `sed` is better choice.

Note once I have an improve solution that's verified working, I'll toss out the `*.tmp` file stuff, and just operate directly on the target file, hence a single `sed -i` command could potentially do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU awk you can specify that your input is in fixed width fields. For example,

```
awk -v OFS='' -v FIELDWIDTHS='6 5 6 6 6 6 6' '
/^HETATM/{ $2 = sprintf("%5d",++count) };1' file.pdb
```

This will edit field 2 of width 5 to an increasing number.

Comment: Perfect this is much cleaner.  I appreciate the help.  Also since I only care about the second field I can shorten it to `awk -v OFS='' -v FIELDWIDTHS='6 5 69' '/^HETATM/{ $2 = sprintf("%5d",++count) };1' file.pdb`!